# Laravel - Stop multiple queries chaining

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I currently have functionality to get some statistics back from my database, using the Query Builder, not Eloquent.

Lets say I want to get a count of the number of users who have an iOS token, and then users who have an android token in one of my tables.

```
class Connection {
    public function __construct()
    {
        return $this->db = DB::connection('database_one');
    }
}

class Statistics extends Connection {
    public function devices()
    {
        $this->devices = $this->db->table('users_devices');

        $arr = [
            'ios' => $this->devices->where('ios_push_token', '!=', '')->count(),
            'android' => $this->devices->where('android_push_token', '!=', '')->count(),
        ];

        return $arr;        
    }
}
```

The query to get the `ios` devices is correct:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `users_devices` where `ios_push_token` != ?
array (size=1)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
```

However, I then hit an issue with the `android` value, the query tries to execute:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `users_devices` where `ios_push_token` != ? and `android_push_token` != ?
array (size=2)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
```

It seems to be chaining the where clause from the first query onto the second query, and so on for multiple instances of this giving me incorrect data.

I think it's something to do with using the one instance of `DB::connection`, but I'm not sure?

Comment: Just use meaningful names. `$this->devices` is not `devices`, but `Query\Builder` instance, so obviously you need 2 such instances for separate queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
class Statistics {
    public function devices()
    {
        $arr = [
            'ios' => DB::table('users_devices')->where('ios_push_token', '!=', '')->count(),
            'android' => DB::table('users_devices')->where('android_push_token', '!=', '')->count(),
        ];

        return $arr;        
    }
}
```

Or clone the object:

```
class Connection {
    public function __construct()
    {
        return $this->db = DB::connection('database_one');
    }
}

class Statistics extends Connection {
    public function devices()
    {
        $this->devices = $this->db->table('users_devices')->remember(30); // etc.

        $ios = clone $this->devices;
        $android= clone $this->devices;

        $arr = [
            'ios' => $ios->where('ios_push_token', '!=', '')->count(),
            'android' => $android->where('android_push_token', '!=', '')->count(),
        ];

        return $arr;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this works, I was hoping to be able to do the method above, then I could easily attach something like `->remember(30)` after where I declare the table... not ideal if I have to do it many times, and also name the same table over and over.

Comment: Cheers for the edit. So clone works :) Shame I can't assign all the variables to the one clone (me being lazy).

Comment: You can also create a private method to get the devices table and call $this->devicesTable()->where(...)